# Meteor + React Mantra offline application atempt

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

After reading and following Ken Rogers very good book: Meteor + React; we successfully started the creation of a new application using Mantra amazing architecture.

But unfortunately we reached about 40% of total development and tested yesterday our new app but in an offline behavior. In order to achieve it I installed GroundDB and Appcache:

```
meteor add appcache
meteor add ground:db
```

After changing all Mongo.Collection to Ground.Collection, we suddenly got weird errors like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'Vendedor' of undefined

It seems like Mantra or React cannot be used at all in an offline manner.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was found that GroundDB could not be used correctly in Meteor last versions.

So recently we started using GroundDB II rc6 in conjunction with subs-cache.

That way we could accomplish what we needed:

https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db/issues/186

Comment: beside GroundDB, do you use any other packages/modules to achieve offline web app?

Comment: Hello, to achieve offline web app, we currently use: ground:db@2.0.0-rc.6 ccorcos:subs-cache (or some fork, since it has some problems) and appcache. Regards.

Comment: I have heard a lot about Service Worker recently that it is to replace appcache. Have you try it?

Comment: No, not yet tried it, but I have read several pages like this:

Comment: No, we have not tried it yet, but I have read several sources like https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-and-service-workers/1765/9 and found that Service Workers for meteor still are in very early stages, as you can see in this component: https://github.com/NitroBAY/meteor-service-worker. We still have some issues with GroundDB that we are fixing. We also thought we could try RethinkDB https://github.com/Slava/meteor-rethinkdb but it has a known issue as you can see at the end of https://github.com/Slava/meteor-rethinkdb/issues/24